# Conditionals used in a new environment of detection of how many lines of quotation and with the selection of a language in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, environments, conditionals, quoting, ifthenelse

I would like that a new environment of quotation/quote detect how many lines a text has, then will increase or decrease the quotation length/margin.

For example:

```
\newenvironment{citacao}[1]%
  {\list{}
    % if a quotation has less than 3 lines, it will be set to 1.cm
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\citacao}{true}}
    {%
        \setlength{\citacao}{1.8cm}
    }
    % if a quotation has more than 3 lines, it will be set to 4cm
    {% else
        \setlength{\citacao}{4cm}
    }
  }%
  {\endlist}
```

If a new environment detects that a quotation has more than 3 lines, it will set the text to 4cm, if not, the text will be set to 1.8cm. Similar to:

```
\newenvironment{citacao}[1]%
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=1.8cm\rightmargin=1.8cm}\item[]}%
  {\endlist}

\newenvironment{citacao}[1]%
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=4cm\rightmargin=4cm}\item[]}%
  {\endlist}
```

I also would like to add the selection of a language for hyphenation like:

```
\newenvironment{citacao}[1][english]%
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=1.8cm\rightmargin=1.8cm}\item[]}%
  {\endlist}
```

I tried to code like:

```
\newenvironment{citacao}[2]%
  {\selectotherlanguage[#1]\list{}
    % if a quotation has less than 3 lines, it will be set to 1.cm
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\citacao}{true}}
    {%
        \setlength{\citacao}{1.8cm}
    }
    % if a quotation has more than 3 lines, it will be set to 4cm
    {% else
        \setlength{\citacao}{4cm}
    }
  }%
  {\endlist}
```

Observe that I use XeLaTeX and the package `csquotes`.

Comment: More than three lines under what line width?

Comment: It is under 4cm.

Comment: You want to automate modified `abnt` rules and make them look more rational. This is where good sense flies out of the window.

Comment: @Joseph, actually, I use `memoir` instead of `abntex2`, because I want to have much freedom to customise. I am using @gcedo's[Thesis Polimi](https://github.com/gcedo/master-thesis). The problem is that in his thesis, he used `caption` and `titlesec` which are not good for the class `memoir`. As I use XeLaTeX, `epstopdf` that he used in his package is not good for XeLaTeX. I have to look for the alternatives, to make them functional with `babel`, `memoir` and XeLaTeX. I also use `biblatex-abnt` because I hate `bibtex` and `natbib`.

Comment: Do you really have to follow `abnt` rules? Just asking, because if you do, your "customization" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your quotations are single paragraphs, this will work: the idea is to typeset the paragraph with the wide margins and use `\prevgraf` to know the number of lines. If the number is greater than 3, the margin is reduced when calling `\list`.

The same idea could be used for multiparagraph quotations, with some complications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{environ}

\newlength{\citacaoindent}
\setlength{\citacaoindent}{4cm}

\NewEnviron{citacao}[1][english]{%
  \csname otherlanguage*\endcsname{#1}%
  \setbox0=\vbox{
    \hsize=\dimexpr\hsize-2\citacaoindent\relax
    \BODY\par\expandafter
  }\expandafter\ifnum\the\prevgraf>3 \setlength{\citacaoindent}{1.8cm}\fi
  \list{}{\leftmargin=\citacaoindent \rightmargin=\citacaoindent}
  \item[]\BODY
  \endlist
}

\begin{document}

\begin{citacao}
This is a short quotation in \languagename,
typeset with a wide margin.
\end{citacao}

\begin{citacao}
This is a long quotation in \languagename, that should be
typeset with a narrower margin
because it fills more than three lines
because it fills more than three lines
because it fills more than three lines
because it fills more than three lines.
\end{citacao}

\begin{citacao}[latin]
This is a short quotation in \languagename,
typeset with a wide margin.
\end{citacao}

\begin{citacao}[latin]
This is a long quotation in \languagename, that should be
typeset with a narrower margin
because it fills more than three lines
because it fills more than three lines
because it fills more than three lines
because it fills more than three lines.
\end{citacao}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for having forgotten that I use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`. Do `setmainlanguage` and `setotherlanguage`  work  `babel`?

Comment: @GustavoReis No, but the code works the same if you remove the `polyglossia` settings and do `\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}`. I changed the code.